# Factorials and never ending cycles!

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence, factorial

As you may know it, the factorial of a positive integer `n` is the product of all the positive integers which are equal or smaller to `n`.

For instance :

```
6! = 6*5*4*3*2*1 = 720
0! = 1
```

We will now define a special operation with an irrelevant name like `sumFac`:

Given a positive integer `n`, `sumFac(n)` is the sum of the factorials of the digits.

For instance :

`sumFac(132) = 1! + 3! + 2! = 9`

### Task

Your mission, whether or not you choose to accept it, is to return the sequence (potentially infinite) of the applications of `sumFac` to an integer given in input.

Example : `132 -> 132, 9, 362880, 81369, 403927, ...`

But that's not all! Indeed, the applications of `sumFac` will eventually create a cycle. You must also return this cycle!

If your language has a built in factorial you can use it.
I'm not picky about the return type, you just have to return the sequence of sumFac applications and the cycle in a format understandable by a human.

EDIT : To help you visualize better what should the output look like I copied Leaky Nun's just below:

```
[132, 9, 362880, 81369, 403927, 367953, 368772, 51128, 40444, 97, 367920, 368649, 404670, 5810, 40442, 75, 5160, 842, 40346, 775, 10200, 6, 720, 5043, 151, 122, 5, 120, 4, 24, 26, 722, 5044, 169, 363601, 1454]
```

You just need to stop the sequence when the cycle is about to start for the second time!

But this is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/100823/48934)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This looks like a nice challenge, BTW.

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp Thank you very much! I tried to be creative ^^

Comment: @Zgarb Well it's exactly like the output of Leaky Nun. The sequence of the applications and then it shall end just before the beginning of the second cycle. I'll copy his output in the question so everyone can have a clear understanding. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @Antoine `1454` actually maps to `169`. Should I just print the cycle or should I print everything from the start?

Comment: @LeakyNun You need to print everything that comes before the cycle and end the sequence with the cycle. Which is what you did because the next number would indeed be 169

Comment: [Related OEIS](http://oeis.org/A188284)

Comment: How important is the output formatting? Can we have the trailing comma, can the values be separated by a space or a newline instead?

Comment: Hardcoding the value 169 is cheating?

Comment: @2501 Hardcoding the value is cheating, but concerning the output formatting you can use any separator you want

Comment: @Antoine Ok. The constant 169 doesn't help anyway, since some cycles don't contain it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
D!SµÐĿ
    ÐĿ  Repeat until the results are no longer unique. Collects all intermediate results.
D           Convert from integer to decimal (list of digits)
 !          Factorial (each digit)
  S         Sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@@iGHxo6@EJR/b////f0NgIAA)

I don't see any other way to make it shorter other than to do as told.

### Specs

- Input: `132` (as command-line argument)
- Output: `[132, 9, 362880, 81369, 403927, 367953, 368772, 51128, 40444, 97, 367920, 368649, 404670, 5810, 40442, 75, 5160, 842, 40346, 775, 10200, 6, 720, 5043, 151, 122, 5, 120, 4, 24, 26, 722, 5044, 169, 363601, 1454]`

Comment: I didn't expect to have an answer that short. Nice :)

Comment: @Antoine It's Jelly :D It's always shorter than I think it'll be ;)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Somehow Dennis will come with an even shorter answer

Comment: Somehow, yes. Because Dennis. :P

Comment: So... Which character encoding do you use to come up with 6 bytes for those 6 characters? Isn't Jelly supposed to be UTF-8 encoded, meaning that this program is actually 9 bytes?

Comment: @LordOfThePigs [Jelly code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

Comment: I see, thanks for educating me. I'm a noob at Code Golfing :-)

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99FMfhY17E1////NzQ2AgA)

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 88 bytes

```python
import math
f=lambda x,l=[]:l*(x in l)or f(sum(math.factorial(int(i))for i in`x`),l+[x])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FcsxCoAwDEDR3VNkTFQEdRM8iQiNSjGQWqkVevta5/9@Fnf7EMFxPCs7K7vtYEitzss6aY0J5AIlH8Di8zr8XWd5jz4IK8oVUYhs6VKkSYZabZa0Ur5DieXqx4HyBw)

Comment: As a python fan I'm glad someone answered with it, nice :)

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
[DˆS!O©¯så#®
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@x/tcrotWNH/0MpD64sPL1U@tO7/f0NjIwA)

**Explanation**

```
[               # infinite loop
 Dˆ             # add a copy of current value to the global list (initialized as input)
   S            # split current number to digits
    !O          # calculate factorial of each and sum
      ©         # save a copy in register
       ¯så#     # if the current number is in the global list, exit loop
           ®    # retrieve the value from the register for the next iteration
                # implicitly output the global list
```

Comment: Short and correct, well played !

Comment: Thought I could get rid of the `s`, was wrong, nice answer.

Answer (score 8):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 17 bytes

```
g:I{tẹḟᵐ+}ᵃ⁾L¬≠Lk
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#ASYA2f//ZzpJe3ThurnhuJ/htZArfeG1g@KBvkzCrOKJoExr//8xMzL/Wg)

#### Explanation

```
g:I{     }ᵃ⁾         Accumulate I (a variable) times, with [Input] as initial input:
    t                  Take the last integer
     ẹḟᵐ+              Compute the sum of the factorial of its digits
            L        The result of the accumulation is L
            L¬≠      Not all elements of L are different
               Lk    Output is L minus the last one (which is the start of the loop)
```

Comment: What does `I` mean?

Comment: @LeakyNun It's a parameter to `ᵃ⁾`. `ᵃ³` means "accumulate 3 times". `ᵃ⁾` means "accumulate as many times as the last element of the input", which in that case is `I`. Since `I` is a completely free variable, it will try values for it from `0` to `+inf`.

Answer (score 8):

## Wolfram Language, <s>62</s> <s>60</s> 56 bytes

```
Most@NestWhileList[Tr[IntegerDigits@#!]&,#,UnsameQ,All]&
```

It is really too bad that Wolfram Language has such abominably long function names. *Sigh*

**Explanation:**

```
Most[NestWhileList[Tr[IntegerDigits[#]!]&,#,UnsameQ,All]]&
                      IntegerDigits[#]                     (*Split input into list of digits*)
                                      !                    (*Factorial each element in the list*)
                   Tr[                 ]&                  (*Sum the list together*)
     NestWhileList[                      ,#,UnsameQ,All]   (*Iterate the function over itself, pushing each to a list, until a repeat is detected*)
Most[                                                   ]& (*Remove the last element in the list*)
```

Comment: Nice answer. I don't think this can be improved upon.

Comment: @KellyLowder Thanks! I was actually able to save two more bytes by mapping the factorial to the list, then summing it with `Tr`.

Comment: Nice use of `NestWhileList[...,All]`!

Answer (score 6):

## ClojureScript, <s>146</s> 109 bytes

```clj
#(loop[n[%]](let[f(apply +(for[a(str(last n))](apply *(range 1(int a))))](if(some #{f}n)n(recur(conj n f)))))
```

Yikes, that is a monstrosity. Someone please help me golf this...

Thanks `@cliffroot` for shaving off a whopping 37 bytes!

This is an anonymous function, to run the function, you have to do this:

```clj
(#(...) {arguments})
```

TIO doesn't have ClojureScript, so [here's a link](http://clojurescript.io/) to a ClojureScript REPL.

[Here's a link](https://tio.run/nexus/clojure#dVJBboQwDLzzipEqVaEVEvuAvgTtwQqBpgIHQTisVn07dZKNmm53cyBoZmyP7RyqNwNjIO0bfdGTQcfnClCTc4v87/MWkAAF0Hh0UStEhNJJxObXhqHkEoA2jxBd1@dCKFJalumC9z@gwINb0RHUSjwaKO129ogZ7zMUWd7@EcgZTg8oIS3rh0SIM9Q3UtHy@ESC2NxTUmj2n8k0qM4nu1d2kHg3G7xc8wy/04zityqc6L0sI9Pgr6hBDkypqyqtr5nJMrpX0DpuxfoI7W1zofYHCKe2baWcnbKp3v3WXaR3P4n32/5U8SxCP3cO4zRzo4eKJurjBw) to a Clojure program which prints the last element in the list from 0 to 1000.

Here's the output for `9999`:

```clj
[9999 1451520 269 363602 1455 265 842 40346 775 10200 6 720 5043 151 122 5 120 4 24 26 722 5044 169 363601 1454]
```

I have a strong suspicion that all numbers must eventually settle at `1` or the loop `[169 363601 1454]`.

### Ungolfed code:

```clj
(defn fact-cycle [n]
  (loop [nums [n]]
    (let [fact-num
          (let [str-n (str (last nums))]
            (apply +
              (for [a (range (count str-n))]
                (apply *
                  (range 1
                    (inc (int (nth str-n a))))))))]
      (if (some #{fact-num} nums) nums
        (recur
          (conj nums fact-num))))))
```

Explanation coming soon!

Comment: Quite long but correct ;) I cannot really help you to golf this sorry ^^

Comment: the inner `for` can be
`(for[a s](apply *(range 1(-(int a)47))))`, can't it?

Comment: and this will allow to get rid of the other `let` 
`#(loop[n[%]](let[f(apply +(for[a(str(last n))](apply *(range 1(-(int a)47)))))](if(some #{f}n)n(recur(conj n f)))))`

Comment: oh, seems you don't even need `(- ... 47)` in ClojureScript, just `int` will suffice

Comment: well,  `(inc(int a))` should do for ClojureScript and `(-(int a)47)` for Clojure.

Comment: `(1), (2), (169, 363601, 1454), (363601, 1454, 169), (1454, 169, 363601), (871, 45361), (145), (45361, 871), (45362, 872), (872, 45362), (40585)` are all cycles for `n <= 10000000`, so there are more than just `[1] and [169 363601 1454]`

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>91</s> 89 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to fəˈnɛtɪk*

It turns out to be quite similar to [the other JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117596/58563).

```js
f=(n,x=!(a=[n]))=>n?f(n/10|0,x+(F=n=>n?n--*F(n):1)(n%10)):~a.indexOf(x)?a:f(x,!a.push(x))
```

```js
f=(n,x=!(a=[n]))=>n?f(n/10|0,x+(F=n=>n?n--*F(n):1)(n%10)):~a.indexOf(x)?a:f(x,!a.push(x))

console.log(f(132))
```

Comment: In your factorial function shouldn't you be able to use n instead of n>1 because 0!=1?

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk I don't know what I was thinking here. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 64 bytes

```perl6
{my@a;$_,{[+] .comb.map:{[*] 2..$_}}...^{$_∈@a||!@a.push: $_}}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u25sqtVFArLs3VTUtMLskvykzMUbD9X51b6ZBorRKvUx2tHaugl5yfm6SXm1hgVR2tFatgpKenEl9bq6enF1etEv@oo8MhsaZG0SFRr6C0OMNKAST3vzixUgHVUENjI2suTGELbIKGJqYm1v8B)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{

  my @a;             # array of values already seen

  $_,                # seed sequence with the input

  {
    [+]              # reduce using &infix:<+>
      .comb          # the digits of $_ (implicit method call)
      .map:          # do the following for each
      {
        [*] 2..$_    # get the factorial of
      }
  }


  ...^               # keep generating values until
                     # (｢^｣ means throw away the last value when done)

  {
      $_ ∈ @a        # is it an elem of @a? (｢∈｣ is shorter than ｢(cont)｣)

    ||               # if it's not

      !              # boolean invert so this returns False
        @a.push: $_  # add the tested value to @a
  }
}
```

Every line above that has `{` starts a new bare block lambda with an implicit parameter of `$_`.

I used `[*] 2..$_` instead of `[*] 1..$_` purely as a micro optimization.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 92 bytes

Thanks @Shaggy for golfing off one byte with includes
Thanks @Neil for golfing off two bytes

**Code separated into individual functions 92 bytes**

```javascript
f=(x,a=[])=>a.includes(x)?a:f(k(x),a,a.push(x))
p=y=>y?y*p(y-1):1
k=n=>n?p(n%10)+k(n/10|0):0
```

**Code on one line 92 bytes**

```javascript
f=(x,a=[])=>a.includes(x)?a:f((k=n=>n?(p=y=>y?y*p(y-1):1)(n%10)+k(n/10|0):0)(x),a,a.push(x))
```

### Explanation

Initially call the function with just a single argument, therefore a=[].

If x exists in the array a return a `a.includes(x)?a:...`

Otherwise, append x to a and pass the factorial digit sum and a to the function `(a.push(x),f(k(x),a))`

```javascript
p=y=>y?y*p(y-1):1
k=n=>n?p(n%10)+k(n/10|0):0
```

Factorial Digit sum performed so that it will not exceed the maximum recursion limit.

**List of all possible endpoints:** 1, 2, 145, 169, 871, 872, 1454, 40585, 45361, 45362, 363601

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#DcbBCgIhEADQ@/5HMFOuad2E0Q@JDsO2ViijIAsr9O@27/RGJNgV0@OJ5Fl/Zcnba22wY2AXIR1RrFjXrX2O41Spk@@hnyv02aKzUyIhL6GCnKzBSwK5WvMz6MxYirSSV53LGyLY@w1x/AE)

Comment: Gah, I was so close! Save a byte with `f=(x,a=[])=>a.includes(x)?a:(a.push(x),f(k(x),a))`

Comment: Can you not write `f(k(x),a,a.push(x))`? Also, I think you can write `k=n=>n&&` to save another byte.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>80</s> 67 bytes

```hs
g#n|elem n g=g|h<-g++[n]=h#sum[product[1..read[d]]|d<-show n]
([]#)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#BcFBCoAgEADAe69YsEMRBtU1X7LsQdI0yE006eLfbaY5wdXeNgCDU676XbppQiblRS4BY3pMOV5c5jlZbdAQVbPL7J8PmLpTDUhibEFfDApiuviFHk5YtrX9) Usage: `([]#) 132`

Edit: Saved 13 bytes with typs from Ørjan Johansen!

Comment: (1) Test and append `n` instead of `s`(same as in ovs's Python answer), then `f=([]#)`. (2) Switch the branches, inline `s`, and use `elem`.

Comment: Switch out your `++` for `:` also.

Comment: @Canyon It's the wrong order around for that, it would give the final result reversed. You can *almost* fix it up afterwards, by prepending an extra `n:` and changing `=g` to `=[]`, but it seems to be only a tie.

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
.us.!MjNT
.us.!MjNTQ  implicit Q

.u          explained below
       N      current value
      j T     convert to decimal (list of digits)
   .!M        factorial of each digit
  s           sum
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.us.%21MjNT&input=132&debug=0)

This answer uses `.u` ("Cumulative fixed-point. Apply until a result that has occurred before is found. Return all intermediate results.")

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 30 bytes

```
W!hxYQQ=+YQKQ=Q0WK=+Q.!%KT=/KT
```

[Try It Here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=W%21hxYQQ%3D%2BYQKQ%3DQ0WK%3D%2BQ.%21%25KT%3D%2FKT&input=132&debug=0)

Comment: Pyth has more useful functions than one imagines. See [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117669/48934) as reference.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 110 bytes

```python
g=lambda x:x<1or x*g(x-1)
def f(n):
 a=[];b=n
 while b not in a:a+=[b];yield b;b=sum(g(int(x))for x in str(b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#PcxNCsMgEEDhvaeY5UxLF7Y7U08SsnDwp4IxxRhqT28SCt0@Pl4POpmZrYGm2lMuBdolYLtJEtZ58JhJCTB6nAbWWcDnFZMDhrxUiBmMMlc98jR8o0sW@EDrNmPAmCs2In8OT7jWgkzU/8GjfNxJvctP9h0)

Answer (score 2):

## R, 120 Bytes

```
o=scan()
repeat {
q=sum(factorial(as.double(el(strsplit(as.character(o[length(o)]), "")))))
if(q%in%o)break
o=c(o,q)
}
o
```

Comment: you can do `o=scan()`, use `el()` instead of `[[1]]`, and `gamma(n+1)=factorial(n)` which I believe saves a byte, and I think `as.numeric` is the same as `as.double` for integers, which also saves a byte, and you can use `toString` instead of `as.character`.

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks for the input, updated.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 9 JSHell, 213 bytes

```
n->{Set<Integer>s=new HashSet<>();
return IntStream.iterate(n,i->(""+i).chars()
.map(x->x<50?1:IntStream.rangeClosed(2,x-48)
.reduce(1,(a,b)->a*b)).sum()).boxed()
.takeWhile(x->s.add(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk9#bVCxTsMwEN3zFVYnuyQWLSAh0oahEgIJpgwMiOGSXFODY0f2paSq@u3FoamQELc8@b1357unmtY6Yh@wBdmR0nKaRuovt@5MScqaf0VPDqEZpKjtCq1KVmrwnr2AMmwfsVAj7wkowNaqijVB5Tk5Zeq3dwau9mI0D/Uwfrh4MoQ1upg9K0/nV5axNVseTZLtc/xl/dLgF3sEvxnYjIvUIXXOsGDIT0sqQgeE3MQqyfhkcqGELDfgPBeygZb3SdYvbi7vZ3e/PQ5MjSttPVZ8HvfJ9a2QDquuRD6LOcSFSDKYFkJI3zU8QGH7YBWS4BNfN0rjMNZLqCreB7m0WmNJfHVC67wkO5wXetPD8RxBmu88YSNtR7INMZE2fC2hbfWOD3fmJRiDjo82ZYQ02FPYO8wR6U@Uh@hwnF3NvwE)

Note: This solution relies on the string representation of a number having code points in the range 48-57. Works for ASCII, UTF-8, Latin-1, all ISO-8859-* character sets, most code pages. Does not work for EBCDIC. I don't think anyone will deduct points for that. :)

Ungolfed:

```
Function<Integer, List<Integer>> f =        // function from Integer to List of Integer
n -> {
    Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();       // memo of values we've seen
    return IntStream.iterate(n,             // iterate over n, f(n), f(f(n)), etc.
    i -> (""+i).chars()                     // the sumFac function; for all chars
        .map(x -> x < 50? 1 :               // give 1 for 0! or 1!
        IntStream.rangeClosed(2, x-48)      // else produce range 2..d 
        .reduce(1,(a,b)->a*b))              // reduction to get the factorial
        .sum())                             // and sum up the factorii!

                                            // now we have a stream of ints
                                            // from applying sumFac repeatedly
        .boxed()                            // box them into Integers (thanks, Java)
        .takeWhile(x->s.add(x))             // and take them while not in the memo
        .collect(Collectors.toList());      // collect them into a list
}
```

Notes:

- The return value of Set::add is very helpful here; returns true **iff** the item was not in the set
- I was being sarcastic when I said "Thanks, Java"
- *factorii* isn't really a word; I just made that up

Comment: I admit this is original ! Nice job :)

Comment: @Antoine I admit, Java isn't the best language to golf in, but it's hardly the craziest thing I've done lately. :) https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117644/794

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>22</s> 11 bytes

```
.usm.!sd+Nk
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.usm.%21sd%2BNk&input=132&debug=0)

Lots of credit to [Leaky Nun's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117669/52152), which introduced me to `.u`, and helped save a massive 11 bytes of this program.

Explanation:

```
.usm.!sd+NkQ | ending Q is implicitly added
             | Implicit: Q = eval(input())
.u         Q | Repeat the function with initial value Q until a previous value is found. Return all intermediate values
  s          | Summation
   m.!sd     | For each character 'd' in the string, convert to integer and take the factorial
        +Nk  | Convert function argument to string
```

Comment: Pyth has more useful functions than one imagines. See [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117669/48934) as reference.

Comment: @LeakyNun I've rewritten my answer to use `.u`. I guess I'll need to take a look through the character reference again to see if there are any other useful functions there.

Comment: You can use `\`N` to convert to string instead of `+Nk`.

Comment: @LeakyNun Where the `N` would be obsolete then, and there comes a 9-byte solution...

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
U¡oṁΠd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/TQwvyHOxvPLUj5//@/obERAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Axiom, 231 bytes

```
l(a:NNI):List NNI==(r:List NNI:=[];repeat(r:=cons(a rem 10,r);a:=a quo 10;a=0=>break);r)
g(a:NNI):NNI==reduce(+,[factorial(x) for x in l(a)])
h(a:NNI):List NNI==(r:=[a];repeat(a:=g(a);member?(a,r)=>break;r:=cons(a,r));reverse(r))
```

not golfed functions and some test

```
-- convert one NNI in its list of digits
listify(a:NNI):List NNI==
    r:List NNI:=[]
    repeat
        r:=cons(a rem 10,r)
        a:=     a quo 10
        a=0=>break
    r

-- g(1234)=1!+2!+3!+4!
SumfactorialDigits(a:NNI):NNI==reduce(+,[factorial(x) for x in listify(a)])

ListGenerateFromSumFactorialDigits(a:NNI):List NNI==
    r:=[a]
    repeat
       a:=SumfactorialDigits(a)
       member?(a,r)=>break
       r:=cons(a,r)
    reverse(r)

(9) -> h 132
   (9)
   [132, 9, 362880, 81369, 403927, 367953, 368772, 51128, 40444, 97, 367920,
    368649, 404670, 5810, 40442, 75, 5160, 842, 40346, 775, 10200, 6, 720,
    5043, 151, 122, 5, 120, 4, 24, 26, 722, 5044, 169, 363601, 1454]
```

Answer (score 1):

### C, 161 bytes

```
f(a){return a?a*f(a-1):1;}
a(l){return l?f(l%10)+a(l/10):0;}
c,t,o;r(i){for(t=o=i;t=a(t),o=a(a(o)),c=t^o;);for(t=i;t^c;printf("%d ",t),c=c|t^o?c:o,t=a(t),o=a(o));}
```

[See it work online.](https://ideone.com/FiF0VM)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, <s>85</s> <s>79</s> <s>64</s> 60 bytes

```
:Prompt L₁                             //Get input as 1 length list, 4 bytes
:Lbl C                                //create marker for looping, see below, 3 bytes
:int(10fPart(Xseq(10^(~A-1),A,0,log(X //split input into list of digits, 20 bytes
:sum(Ans!→X                           //factorial and sum the list, write to new input, 6 bytes
:If prod(L₁-X                         //Test to see if new element is repeated, see below, 7 bytes
:Then                                 //Part of If statement, 2 bytes
:augment(L₁,{X→L₁                     //Push new input to List 1, 10 bytes
:Goto C                               //Loop back to beginning, 3 bytes
:Else                                 //Part of If statement, 2 bytes
:L₁                                   //Print Answer, 2 bytes
```

Since this is running on a graphing calculator, there is limited RAM. Try testing it with numbers that loop quickly, like `169`.

**More Explanation:**

```
:int(10fPart(Xseq(10^(~A-1),A,0,log(X
              seq(10^(~A-1),A,0,log(X //Get a list of powers of 10 for each digit (i.e. 1, 0.1, 0.01, etc.)
             X                        //Multiply by input
       fPart(                         //Remove everything but the decimal
     10                               //Multiply by 10 (move one digit in front of the decimal
:int(                                 //Truncate to an integer
```

`If prod(L₁-X` works by subtracting the new element from the old list, then multiplying all the elements of the list together. If the element was already in the list, the product will be `0`, a falsey value. Otherwise, the product will be a positive integer, a truthy value.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 220 bytes

```
String c(int n){String r=n+",",c;for(;!r.matches("^"+(c=(n=d(n))+",")+".*|.*,"+c+".*");r+=c);return r;}int d(int n){int s=0;for(String i:(n+"").split(""))s+=f(new Long(i));return s;}long f(long x){return x<2?1:x*f(x-1);}
```

**Explanation:**

```
String c(int n){                            // Method with integer parameter and String return-type
  String r=n+",",                           //  Result-String (which starts with the input integer + a comma
         c;                                 //  Temp String
  for(;!r.matches(                          //  Loop as long as the result-String doesn't match the following regex:
    "^"+(c=(n=d(n))+",")+".*|.*,"+c+".*");  //    "^i,.*|.*,i,.*" where `i` is the current integer
                                            //   `n=d(n)` calculates the next integer in line
                                            //   `c=(n=d(n))+","` sets the temp String to this integer + a comma
    r+=c                                    //   And append the result-String with this temp String
  );                                        //  End of loop
  return r;                                 //  Return the result-String
}                                           // End of method

int d(int n){                               // Separate method (1) with integer parameter and integer return-type
  int s=0;                                  //  Sum
  for(String i:(n+"").split(""))            //  Loop over the digits of `n`
    s+=f(new Long(i));                      //   And add the factorial of these digits to the sum
                                            //  End of loop (implicit / single-line body)
  return s;                                 //  Return the sum
}                                           // End of separate method (1)

long f(long x){                             // Separate method (2) with long parameter and long return-type (calculates the factorial)
                                            // (NOTE: 2x `long` and the `new Long(i)` is shorter than 2x `int` and `new Integer(i)`, hence long instead of int)
  return x<2?                               //  If `x` is 1:
      1                                     //   return 1
    :                                       //  Else:
      x*f(x-1);                             //   return `x` multiplied by the recursive-call of `x-1`
}                                           // End of method (2)
```

**Test code:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#PY4xb4MwEIX3/IqrpzugVki3uFbnSs2UMUol1wFiCQyyTUtF@e3UIFoP99757PedrpX3cBrnc3DGVqDR2ACWxq130qYsY5kWZetQPDjeqKDvhUf2zlLUEq28oSVaXsXCkx@eZCzVi2UkXCp1rEXonQUnpiX99sdYxMv9Gr3xzBEjkBH3XW0CRkc@lSXa4gveWluhof84L6Y6XkGJqww0boPh@fCSH4ekxOExJzHNAF3/URsNPqgQ5bM1N2iUsRv2cgVF4w7iOX/7UDS87QPv4ijUdmWfkLhe3asNRVU4VJf9leIy8de0m@Y5fzr8Ag)

```
class M{
  String c(int n){String r=n+",",c;for(;!r.matches("^"+(c=(n=d(n))+",")+".*|.*,"+c+".*");r+=c);return r;}int d(int n){int s=0;for(String i:(n+"").split(""))s+=f(new Long(i));return s;}long f(long x){return x<2?1:x*f(x-1);}
  
  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(new M().c(132));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
132,9,362880,81369,403927,367953,368772,51128,40444,97,367920,368649,404670,5810,40442,75,5160,842,40346,775,10200,6,720,5043,151,122,5,120,4,24,26,722,5044,169,363601,1454,
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 44 bytes

```
~]{..)\;10base{,1\{)*}/}%{+}*.@\+@@?)!}do);`

~                                             eval input
 ]                                            initialization
  {                                   }do     do...
   ..)\;                                          initialization
        10base                                    get digits
              {,1\{)*}/}%                         factorial each
                         {+}*                     sum
                             .@\+@@?)!        while result not found
                                         );   drop last element
                                           `  tostring
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/golfscript#@18XW62npxljbWiQlFicWq1jGFOtqVWrX6tarV2rpecQo@3gYK@pWJuSr2md8P@/obERAA)

The factorial part is from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/629/48934).

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>40</strike> 31 bytes

Edit: 9 bytes saved using the improvements by FrownyFrog. Thanks!

```
f=.$:@,~`]@.e.~[:+/@:!10#.inv{:
```

Original code:

```
f=.[`($:@,)@.([:-.e.~)[:+/!@("."0&":@{:)
```

In this case I decided to count the bytes for the verb definition, since otherwise it doesn't work in the interpreter.

Explanation:

```
                         (        {:) - Takes the last element of the array
                               ":@    - converts it to string
                          "."0&       - converts each character back to integer
                       !@             - finds the factorials
                     +/               - sums them
                   [:                 - cap (there are 2 derived verbs above, we need 3 for a fork)
          (    e.~)                   - check if the result is present in the list    
             -.                       - negates the above check
           [:                         - cap
        @.                            - Agenda conjunction, needed for the recursion
  ($:@,)                              - if the result is not in the list, add it to the list and recur
[`                                    - if the result is in the list, display it and stop
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WLzpBQ8XKQUfTQU8j2kpXL1WvTjPaSltf0UFDSU/JQE3JyqHaSvN/anJGvkKagqGR8X8A)

Comment: `([:-.e.~)` -> `(1-e.~)`

Comment: [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT8XKQacuIdZBL1WvLtpKW9/BStHQQFkvM6@s2up/anJGvkKagqGR8X8A)

Comment: @FrownyFrog Thanks, your code is much better!
I tried 10#.inv early while experimenting, but then I wrote it 10&#.inv and it was longer, so I rejected it. Thanks for all your suggestions! I have much to learn :)

Comment: @FrownyFrog  Reversing the cases for the agenda is so good, I regret I didn't see it :)

Comment: `[:+/!@"."0@":@{:` is the same length, so there's no improvement with `10#.inv`. Just had to drop the `()`.

Comment: Yes, I just saw it - its not ambiguous to require ()

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 143 bytes

```
proc P {n L\ ""} {proc F n {expr $n?($n)*\[F $n-1]:1}
while {[set n [expr [join [lmap d [split $n ""] {F $d}] +]]] ni $L} {lappend L $n}
set L}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY69DoMwDIT3PMUJMfRHHWg3lm6dMrAHDwgiNVVqIkjVSlGePTVMPtnf3TmOvpSwzCM6JIbuUVUZad88wEj2FxbUfD/UfDz15iH60lDbZPV9Om@RzGqjgGYHzWt2ov17CJhg1uBdFIeEEpJ4p0w4ExHYodZS5IcQLE/QQmW1Relcdrt0q@Z2Vds3n7jKve3ZdDIpl/IH)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 15 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to @[Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m) and another later

```apl
f←(#+.(!⍎)⍕)⌂traj
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/P@1R2wQNZW09DcVHvX2aj3qnaj7qaSopSswCSikYGhsBAA)

`traj` is a function in the dfns workspace that runs a function until a cycle is detected. Here, that function is `#+.(!⍎)⍕`. `⍕` turns the argument into a string. Each character/digit (`¨`) is executed/turned into a number (`⍎`). `!` finds the factorial of each of these digits. Then `+` adds up all these factorials. `#` is used because `#⍎foo` just executes `foo`, so it's `#f.⍎` is practically the same as `{f/⍎¨⍵}` here.

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>25</s> 20 bytes

Saved 5 bytes thanks to @[Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m)!

```apl
1↓{⍵,⍨+/!⍎¨⍕⊃⍵}⍣(⊃∊)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wTDR22Tqx/1btV51LtCW1/xUW/foRWPeqc@6moGCtY@6l2sAWJ2dGkClSsYGhsBAA)

Output is reversed.

This is very similar to the code above, but uses the power operator (`⍣`) to run the dfn until a cycle is reached, then drops the first element (`1↓`) because it runs 1 extra time. `{⍵,⍨+/!⍎¨⍕⊃⍵}` applies the function in the question to the first element of the argument (`⊃⍵`), then prepends it to the argument (`⍵,⍨`). Each time it is called, the list grows by one. The train `⊃∊` is applied with the next result on the left side and the previous result on the right side and tells ⍣ when to stop. `∊` is membership and tells which of the next result's elements are in the previous results (if one of them is repeated, there is a cycle). Then it picks the first of these booleans (`⊃`) because we need a single value and the rest have been checked already in previous iterations.

Comment: [`#.{+/!⍎¨⍕⍵}⌂traj`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/P@1R2wRlvWptfcVHvX2HVjzqnfqod2vto56mkqLELKC0gqGxEQA) saves a byte.

Comment: [`1↓{⍵,⍨+/!⍎¨⍕⊃⍵}⍣(⊃∊)`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wTDR22Tqx/1btV51LtCW1/xUW/foRWPeqc@6moGCtY@6l2sAWJ2dGkClSsYGhsBAA)

Comment: @Adám Sweet, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 87 bytes

```powershell
param($r)for(;$r-notin$l){$l+=,$r
$r=("$r"|% t*y|%{1.."$_"-ne0-join'*'})-join'+'|iex}$l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcbBCoMwDADQ@75ilEhbXWXqcfgtQ0bEjqyRKOiwfnt22Du9mTeUZUKi8GJB1XmQ4eNA/MjiHiAh8RoTkD@Aqv4GcgHpnQExubiu5TcXR1PXBp4mJLyHN8dkS3v6/yqbI@4nkKo2XfsD)

Thanks to mazzy for saving a lot of bytes!

### Explained (old implementation, but close enough)

```powershell
param($r)for(;$r-notin$l                       # Checks that the last computed value isn't an existing one
                        ){$l+=,$r              # Adds it to the list

$r=("$r"|                                      # Converts r as a string
      % t*y|                                   # Converts it to a char array
      %{1.."$_"-ne0-join'*'}                   # Builds the factorial calculation strings and handles 0!. e.g. 1*2*3*4
   )-join'+'|iex}                              # Joins them with "+" and computes it. e.g. 1*2*3*4+1*2*3

$l                                             # Returns all the values in the list
```

Comment: Thanks. I think you can save some bytes if you use an array instead of hashtable

Comment: I tried but arrays have fixed size and I couldn't find any short way of instantiating one.
i.e. `[System.Collections.ArrayList]::New()`

Comment: Another [117 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcjRCsIgFADQ976i5I7pTGH1GEJfsZcxxggj46ZyXRQ4v90eOo8nho@l9LCI6hbI1hoXWl4cSNwDcUBzzeUCpHxYnQfUw4Jvm0QGHMFJORmgHZDhDIipFNGtjG1N5rzXGmb1DM63XSuOvRgPEuapiP/JdnP2WwC3Zj90tdb@fPoB "PowerShell Core – Try It Online") option that raises a lot of error but returns a correct result

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcbBCoMwDADQ@75ilEhbXWXqcfgtQ0bEjqyRKOiwfnt22Du9mTeUZUKi8GJB1XmQ4eNA/MjiHiAh8RoTkD@Aqv4GcgHpnQExubiu5TcXR1PXBp4mJLyHN8dkS3v6/yqbI@4nkKo2XfsD "PowerShell Core – Try It Online") 【ツ】

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=product,sum -n`, 49 bytes

```perl
say&&($_=sum map{product 1..$_}/./g)until$k{$_}++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJNTUMl3ra4NFchN7GguqAoP6U0uUTBUE9PJb5WX08/XbM0ryQzRyW7GsjX1v7/39DY6F9@QUlmfl7xf11fn8ziEiurUKAKkBE6UO1ACVM9A0OD/7p5AA)

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by changing `&&` to `,`, `)` to a space, and by removing `(`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJHJd62uDRXITexoLqgKD@lNLlEwVBPTyW@Vl9PP12hNK8kM0cluxrI19b@/9/Q2OhffkFJZn5e8X9dX5/M4hIrq1CgCpAROlDtQAlTPQNDg/@6eQA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 72 bytes

```
Most@NestWhileList[Total[IntegerDigits@#!]&,#,DuplicateFreeQ@*List,All]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBCsIwEAXQs0ihizKLegAhQhEEKyqCi5DFINN0YJqW5Hv@qPv3FsYsC0PfXKdDHdcCd5WC16wmFy3wzxVs/pwgUfKgUVFcswstNTR8NvtFyCmL3F3393Q0C20defO3rAmum@jBKYrvad@HUL8)

Keeps applying `sumFac` to it's own output until it sees a duplicate value, then returns a list of all values excluding that final duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
│¼µ\Ä▬Éε╩X
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b3ace65c8e1690eeca58&i=132)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, 65 bytes

```perl
say,(map{$f=1;map{$f*=$_}2..$_;$.+=$f}/./g),$_=$.until$.=$r{$_}++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJHIzexoFolzdbQGsLQslWJrzXS01OJt1bR07ZVSavV19NP19RRibdV0SvNK8nMUdGzVSmqBqrS1v7/39DY6F9@QUlmfl7xf11fUz0DQ4P/unkA)

Uses `map` as regular loops (ignoring return value), and `$.` as a temporary variable (to save space before `until`).

Comment: Note that, under current rules, [command line flags count as separate languages, rather than extra bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/46076), so the correct header for this answer is "Perl 5 -n, 65 bytes"

Comment: @pppery, ok changed